# Prevent Google Translate from translating a variable

Tags: flutter, google-translate, google-translation-api, flutter-localizations, google-translate-api

I see Google Translate, both the web interface and API translates a variable like '`{userName}`'. Is there a way to preserve the variable as it is?

[image]

Context: I have a Flutter project with localization support. The ARB file contains an entry like below. Because Google translate translates the {userName} part (to Spanish in this example), the Spanish version of the app breaks.

```
  "greetingMorningWithName": "Good morning, {userName}!",
  "@greetingMorningWithName": {
    "description": "A message with a single parameter",
    "placeholders": {
      "userName": {
        "type": "String",
        "example": "Bob"
      }
    }
  },
```

Note: If I change the variable name from 'userName' to 'user_Name', it's not translated, but I'd like to avoid it as I want to stick to the camel case convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ARB file` is not supported nor trained by the Translation API.  These are the supported formatted files only:

[image]

**Plain text and HTML** are also trained in the translation models.

You can create a [Glossary](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary) to have your syntax `{userName}` to not be translated and have your customized dictionary. Another workaround is to create a [Custom Model](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/automl-quickstart) where you can **train a model** in ARB file format.